# How to use make to keep a file synced?

Tags: file, recursion, makefile, synchronization

If doing:

```
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash

GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH := ../.gitignore
GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH := ./setup/.gitignore

start_syncing: "${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}"
    printf '\n'

"${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}":
    cp -vr "${GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH}" ./setup/
```

Make keeps running the rule `"${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}"` every time when I call `make`, but it should only call it when the source file `../.gitignore` is modified.

## Update 3

This is the make file I was suggested to use on comment:

```
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash

GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH := ../.gitignore
GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH := ./setup/.gitignore

start_syncing: "${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}"
    printf '\n'

${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}: ${GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH}
    cp -vr "${GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH}" ./setup/
```

Running it, it says:

```
$ ls -l ../.gitignore
-rwx---r-x+ 1 User None 488 Apr 27 23:23 ../.gitignore
$ ls -l ./setup/.gitignore
-rwx---r-x+ 1 User None 488 Apr 28 07:41 ./setup/.gitignore
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target '"./setup/.gitignore"', needed by 'start_syncing'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove double quotes from the target rules. In case they have a space on the name, there is nothing make can do about it other than you manually escape the values of the space with `\`

```
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash

GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH := ../.gitignore
GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH := ./setup/.gitignore

start_syncing: ${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}
    printf '\n'

${GITIGNORE_DESTINE_PATH}: ${GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH}
    cp -vr "${GITIGNORE_SOURCE_PATH}" ./setup/
```